# Object properties don't get passed to a delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have a managed object defined in one .h file:

```
@interface MyItem : NSManagedObject {
NSString *itemName;
NSInteger itemType;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *itemName;
@property NSInteger itemType;

@end
```

And then I have a uiViewController, which has a protocol defined:

```
@protocol uiViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) controllerIsDone:(MyItem *) myItem;
@end
```

Normally, somewhere in implementation of uiViewControler class I invoke this protocol:

```
NSLog(@"Self item has its properties %@ and %i", 
    self.myItem.itemName, self.myItem.itemName);

[[self delegate] controllerIsDone:self.myItem];
```

I have a tableViewController which is a delegate of this uiViewController.

And I have a tableViewController

```
@interface tableViewController : UITableViewController <uiViewControllerDelegate>
```

This tableViewController implements the protocol method:

```
- (void) controllerIsDone:(MyItem *) myItem {
    NSLog("This is what I received %@ and %i", myItem.itemName, myItem.itemType);
}
```

Can you please tell me, why in Console I get this:

```
Self item has its properties SampleName and 1
This is what I received  and 0
```

That is, though I'm passing the self.item of the uiViewController up to tableViewController, it doesn't come with all its properties. Why? How should I pass all the myItem object, so I could use its properties that are set in uiViewController's myItem property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
@interface MyItem : NSManagedObject
```

to

```
@interface MyItem : NSObject
```

fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you retaining `myItem`? Check the pointer value of `myItem` before you pass it and when you receive it:

```
NSLog(@"Self item has its properties %@ and %i, and pointer value %p", 
      self.myItem.itemName, self.myItem.itemName, self.myItem);

- (void) controllerIsDone:(MyItem *) myItem {
    NSLog("This is what I received %@ and %i, and pointer value %p", myItem.itemName, myItem.itemType,myItem);
}
```

If they are not the same (or null in the second case), it probably wasn't retained properly.

Comment: Hmm.  Before you call `controllerIsDone`, try retaining `self.myItem` just for kicks: `[self.myItem retain]`

Comment: What is also interesting, I did more pointers, not only for `self.myItem`, but also for `self.myItem.itemName`. And the latter doesn't stay.

Comment: Fixed myself. You wouldn't have guessed. Sorry. The problem was that MyItem was declared as a `NSManagedObject` (I am preparing my code for Core Data). As soon as I changed it to `NSObject`, it all came alright.

Comment: @Mantvydas -- interesting!  Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. That got me into thinking. :)